# C# save list to binary file

Tags: c#

i have a button in my form that is supposed to take a list and save it to binary file on click. i compile and run the program enter the valued in the text box and click the save button. i look in the project directory and there is no new file. did i code it wrong or miss something?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>();
    oreData.Add(b1);
    oreData.Add(b2);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(fs, oreData);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you look under your bin directory (Debug or Release, depending on which build you're running)?

Comment: OMG i cant believe it was that simple.... well now on to getting it to read that file :) thank you very much

Comment: Also, you may want to append `Application.StartupPath` as the prefix for file names.

Comment: Aside: Personally, I try to discourage people from using `BinaryFormatter` as a persistence format. It has some jagged edges that can *really* hurt you as you evolve your application. There are binary serializers that are far more suitable, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Ore" class must be Serializable

```
[Serializable] Class Ore
{
 . 
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: Would the Ore class have the oreData as one of its elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows Vista or later and you are not explicitly launching your program with admin privileges then I bet it is being written to a shadow directory under the covers as you are not allowed to write to anything in `Program Files`.  [Here is some more info.](http://www.clipboardextender.com/off-topic/vista-program-files-hide-and-seek)