# binary serialization to list

Tags: c#, list, serialization

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487435/c-sharp-save-list-to-binary-file) information to convert a list to .txt with binary serialization. now I want to load that file, and put it again in my list.

this is my code to convert a list to .txt with binary serialization:

```
public void Save(string fileName)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\" + fileName + ".txt", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(fs, list);
    fs.Close();
}
```

so my question is; how to convert this binary file back to a list?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
//Serialize: pass your object to this method to serialize it
public static void Serialize(object value, string path)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fStream, value);
    }
}

//Deserialize: Here is what you are looking for
public static object Deserialize(string path)
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        return formatter.Deserialize(fStream);
    }
}
```

Then use these methods:

```
string path = @"C:\" + fileName + ".txt";

Serialize(list, path);

var deserializedList = Deserialize(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hossein Narimani Rad , I used your answer and changed it a bit (so I understand it more) and now it works.

my binair serialize method (save) is still the same.
this is my binair deserialize method (load):

```
        public void Load(string fileName)
    {
        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter binformat = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (fs2.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("List is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            LoadedList = (List<Object>)binformat.Deserialize(fs2);
            fs2.Close();
            List.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(LoadedList));
            List.AddRange(LoadedList);
        }
```

I know I don't have an exception now, but I understand it better this way.
I also added some code to fill my listbox with my List with the new LoadedList.